# Semantic UI: overriding a variable in site.variables

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I would like to know how to override a variable in `site.variables` file. I am using Semantic UI with Meteor using the official meteor package.

Specifically, I want to override

```
@fontPath  : '/lib/semantic-ui/src/themes/default/assets/fonts';
```

I tried to change the value directly in `site.variables` to no avail. Also, I added a value to `site.override` with no success.

Both files state at the top:

```
/*
  DO NOT MODIFY - This file has been generated and will be regenerated
  Semantic UI v2.0.8
*/
```

Where can I override this value? This is needed to fix [this issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor/issues/55).

Comment: I'm not sure how Meteor works, but where were the files that you changed? You need to change the ones in `src/site/globals` in Semantic UI's folder, those aren't automatically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor#generated-structure), the content of `themes/` directory is not editable - it will get rewritten back when you run your Meteor server.

You need to edit `site.variables.import.less` file in your `site/globals/` directory instead.

Comment: There is no `site/globals` in my project. There is only `site/modules` with two files in it: `accordion.overrides.import.less`, `accordion.variables.import.less`. Is that directory expected to be present? My Semantic UI works well without it. How can I proceed?

Comment: Yes it's expected to be there and it's automatically created in my Semantic UI projects when I use the Semantic UI package for Meteor. There are five folders for me - collections, elements, globals, modules and views, with modules folder having much more files. If you don't have them generated, something is wrong. Try create Semantic UI from scratch. Or maybe you disabled most of modules in custom.semantic.json file?

Comment: I think `semantic:ui` package is a bit brittle when used inside a package. I upgraded to `2.1.3` and tried to generate new file dozen times and now I see that file.